# Add names to a list of weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to add to the query a list of names for each week from another table with names (repeat in order by id)

`Weeknumb` is different from `id`

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019')) as Weeknumb     
    , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 4, '01/01/' + '2019')
        + (DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019'))-1), 4) AS StartOfWeek
    , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 4, '01/01/' + '2019')
        + (DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019'))-1), 11) AS EndOfWeek
FROM master..spt_values t2
WHERE t2.type = 'P'
AND t2.number <= 255
AND YEAR(DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019'))=2019
```

Result:

```
| Weeknumb |          StartOfWeek |            EndOfWeek |
|----------|----------------------|----------------------|
|        1 | 2019-01-04T00:00:00Z | 2019-01-11T00:00:00Z |
|        2 | 2019-01-11T00:00:00Z | 2019-01-18T00:00:00Z |
|        3 | 2019-01-18T00:00:00Z | 2019-01-25T00:00:00Z |
|        4 | 2019-01-25T00:00:00Z | 2019-02-01T00:00:00Z |
|        5 | 2019-02-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-02-08T00:00:00Z |
|        6 | 2019-02-08T00:00:00Z | 2019-02-15T00:00:00Z |
|        7 | 2019-02-15T00:00:00Z | 2019-02-22T00:00:00Z |
|        8 | 2019-02-22T00:00:00Z | 2019-03-01T00:00:00Z |
|        9 | 2019-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-03-08T00:00:00Z |
|       10 | 2019-03-08T00:00:00Z | 2019-03-15T00:00:00Z |
|       11 | 2019-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2019-03-22T00:00:00Z |
```

I have another table with names

```
| id | name |
|----|------|
|  1 |    a |
|  2 |    b |
|  3 |    c |
```

Need to be:

```
| Weeknumb |          StartOfWeek |            EndOfWeek | Name
|----------|----------------------|----------------------|-------
|        1 | 2019-01-04T00:00:00Z | 2019-01-11T00:00:00Z | a
|        2 | 2019-01-11T00:00:00Z | 2019-01-18T00:00:00Z | b
|        3 | 2019-01-18T00:00:00Z | 2019-01-25T00:00:00Z | c
|        4 | 2019-01-25T00:00:00Z | 2019-02-01T00:00:00Z | a
|        5 | 2019-02-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-02-08T00:00:00Z | b
|        6 | 2019-02-08T00:00:00Z | 2019-02-15T00:00:00Z | c
|        7 | 2019-02-15T00:00:00Z | 2019-02-22T00:00:00Z | a
|        8 | 2019-02-22T00:00:00Z | 2019-03-01T00:00:00Z | b
|        9 | 2019-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2019-03-08T00:00:00Z | c
|       10 | 2019-03-08T00:00:00Z | 2019-03-15T00:00:00Z | a
|       11 | 2019-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2019-03-22T00:00:00Z | b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind :

```
select a.Weeknumb
       , a.StartOfWeek
       , a.EndOfWeek
       , b.name from (
       SELECT case when ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019'))) % (select count(1) from testTable2))) = 0 then 3
                   else ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019'))) % (select count(1) from testTable2)))
                   end br
              , DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019')) as Weeknumb     
              , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 4, '01/01/' + '2019') + (DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019'))-1), 4) AS StartOfWeek
              , DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 4, '01/01/' + '2019') + (DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019'))-1), 11) AS EndOfWeek
       FROM master..spt_values t2
       WHERE t2.type = 'P'
       AND t2.number <= 255
       AND YEAR(DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2019'))=2019) a
left join ( select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ) rn, name from  testTable2)b 
on (a.br = b.rn)
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc2b8099dbd92ca1734c44c53d57fd6c)

Comment: Almost, I need the names to repeat over the weeks in the order of the name id. Imagine that there are only 5 names, which repeat for 53 weeks in the same order. in your example as there is no match between ids return null

Comment: Ok, but you say you only have 5 names so 5 ID's. And column Weeknumb has values from 1 to 11. So only values 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 would have a matching value in that column. Is this your plan or you do not need to have a matching value in that column that matches column ID from the second table ?

Comment: I dont need a matching value between tables. (thank you)

Comment: @myke check the update of the demo and code. This is close enough :) is this ok ?

Comment: Damn!!! Thank you so much for your time!!! its good enough for me!!

Comment: You are welcome but that is not all :) I will update my code because I have founded a exact solution: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc2b8099dbd92ca1734c44c53d57fd6c

Comment: Awesome!! i changed 0 then 3 to 0 then (select count(*) from testTable2)

Comment: With last version of code you do not have to change anything. Happy you like it!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a database join.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15

You can join on the results of a SQL query as well as on a table:

```
SELECT t1.a, t2.b
FROM (
  SELECT id, a
  FROM table1
) t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```